# Find the permision that gives a user access to a folder

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs

A user can access a folder that he should not be able to access.  He doesn't seem to have the permissions but it could be a nested group. Is there a way to show all users that have access to a folder and through which group that access was granted?

The server is a windows 2008 sbs

Answer (score 1):

The command "net user [usernameofinterest]" will show the groups the user is in, among other things. See http://www.windows-commandline.com/list-of-user-groups-command-line/. The Windows Explorer "Effective Permissions" tab of the Security Properties dialog for a folder will show the effect of the access controls that have been placed on the folder. I know of no built-in utility that would directly give the results you ask for.

Comment: "net user [usernameofinterest]" only shows default groups.  Is there a way to show all nested groups?